# Directus - Retrieve relations with GraphQL

Tags: graphql, directus

I try to retrieve the relations of the database of my directus app.

I use GraphQL with following endpoint https://myapp.directus.app/graphql.

Using a query for the relations according to the [docs](https://docs.directus.io/reference/system/relations.html#example)

```
query {
    relations {
        collection
        field
    }
}
```

leads to an validation error:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "GraphQL validation error.",
            "extensions": {
                "code": "GRAPHQL_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION",
                "graphqlErrors": [
                    {
                        "message": "Cannot query field "relations" on type "Query". Did you mean "locations"?",
                        "locations": [
                            {
                                "line": 2,
                                "column": 2
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I use Postman so far and started with a query for the database entries

```
query { 
    boards { 
        id 
        columns {
            id
            name
        }
    }
}
```

which works as expected.

What I find interesting is, that Postman shows an mouseover text on the keyword "relations" of the 2nd query -->

```
"Cannot query field relations on type Query. Did you mean locations?"
```

But unfortunately I have no idea what to do with that message.

Any ideas what is wrong here?

Comment: Sure looks like an error in the docs!

Comment: Ok. Any idea or hint how it should be correct?

Comment: Haven't used directus, sorry. Does it have a playground (aka graphiql) that you can use to inspect the schema and build working queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile I found the problem. The endpoint for queries on relations is `https://myapp.directus.app/graphql/system`

With that the query

```
query {
    relations {
        collection
        field
    }
}
```

is working